# Concatenate several np arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have several bumpy arrays and I want to concatenate them. I am using `np.concatenate((array1,array2),axis=1)`. My problem now is that I want to make the number of arrays parametrizable, I wrote this function

```
x1=np.array([1,0,1])
x2=np.array([0,0,1])
x3=np.array([1,1,1])  

def conc_func(*args):
    xt=[]
    for a in args:
        xt=np.concatenate(a,axis=1)
    print xt
    return xt

xt=conc_func(x1,x2,x3)
```

this function returns ([1,1,1]), I want it to return ([1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]). I tried to add the for loop inside the `np.concatenate` as such

```
xt =np.concatenate((for a in args: a),axis=1)
```

but I am getting a syntax error. I can't used neither append nor extend because I have to deal with `numpy arrays` and not `lists`. Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `concatenate` takes a list of arrays (or tuple),  It isn't restricted to a tuple of 2.  And giving it just one array is usually wrong.  `(for a in args: a)` is the wrong syntax for a list comprehension.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) can accept a sequence of array-likes, such as `args`:

```
In [11]: args = (x1, x2, x3)

In [12]: xt = np.concatenate(args)

In [13]: xt
Out[13]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

By the way, although `axis=1` works, the inputs are all 1-dimensional arrays (so they only have a 0-axis). So it makes more sense to use `axis=0` or omit `axis` entirely since the default is `axis=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use numpy? Even if you do, you can convert numpy array to python list, run the following and covert back to numpy.array.

Adding to lists in python will concatenate them...

```
x1=[1,0,1]
x2=[0,0,1]
x3=[1,1,1]

def conc_func(*args):
    xt=args[0]
    print(args)
    for a in args[1:]:
        xt+=a
    print (xt)
    return xt

xt=conc_func(x1,x2,x3)
```